# Requisição de dados, checkout Cielo

Tags: codeigniter, post

Estou com problemas para receber os dados na URL de notificação e de status do Checkout Cielo. Estou usando o framework CodeIgniter, e os dados não fazem update na tabela.

Segue os código do meu Controller Cart:

```
public function notify() {

    $order_number = $this->input->post('order_number'); 
    $mod_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_type'); 
    $name_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_name'); 
    $price_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_price'); 
    $cep_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_adress_zipcode'); 
    $dist_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_adress_district'); 
    $city_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_adress_city'); 
    $state_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_state'); 
    $adre_ship1 = $this->input->post('shipping_adress_line1'); 
    $adre_ship2 = $this->input->post('shipping_adress_line2'); 
    $number_ship = $this->input->post('shipping_adress_number');

    $data = array(
        'order_shipping' => $price_ship,
        'order_status' => $this->input->post('payment_status'),
        'order_tid' => $this->input->post('tid')
    );

    $myOrder = $this->store_model->upMyOrders($order_number, $data);

    $this->load->view('store/notify');
}

public function status() {   

    $order_number = $this->input->post('order_number'); 
    $data = array( 'order_status' => $this->input->post('payment_status'), );
    $myOrder = $this->store_model->upMyOrders($order_number, $data);
    $this->load->view('store/status');
}
```

A página Notify e a Status contém o código

```
<status>OK</status>
```

Store Model

```
public function upMyOrders($order_number, $data) {
  $query = $this->db->where(array('order_number' => $order_number))
  ->update('tb_store_orders', $data);
  return true;
}
```

Tentei por o `$data` dentro do model e também não funcionou.

Não há mudança nenhuma no banco de dados e eu não recebo mensagem de erro da cielo no email..

Comment: Esta linha: $myOrder = $this->store_model->upMyOrders($order_number, $data);, eu particularmente usaria: $this->store_model->upMyOrders($order_number, $data);, caso não dê certo, dê um print_r($myOrder); e veja o que retorna.

Comment: O problema é que essas duas páginas, notify e status, os dados vem da API da Cielo, portanto eu não tenho acesso a elas na página.